# How to generate a list of unknown number of items without using a loop

Tags: c++, stl

Is it possible to generate a list of items if I don't know how many there are in the list, without using a loop?

Here's an example (using a loop):

```cpp
vector<int> bits(int N) {
    vector<int> v;

    while (N != 0) {
        v.push_back(N & 1);
        N >>= 1;
    }

    return v;
}
```

In this example, I don't know how many items the returned vector will have beforehand. And while it is totally fine using a loop to implement this function, my question (as I'm trying to learn C++ and STL) is if there's a way to do the same thing but without any loops.

Comment: This is the fifth _"without using a loop_" I've seen in a short period of time. What's wrong with loops?

Comment: :) AS I said, there's nothing wrong with a loop. For me (at least), it's just a thought exercise. I was wondering if I'm missing some STL function that could do this.

Comment: Fill it with `std::random_device` input? It'll still be a loop, but you won't see it?

Comment: Could you please provide an example? (in the spirit of SO)

Comment: Perhaps - but, in the same spirit, this seems to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Here's my justification: the whole idea of STL is to reduce the need for loops. There are functions for almost everything and each one eliminates the need to iterate over some loop. And I believe that is to make the code more readable. Now, I faced a problem where I needed to generate a list but the size of it was unknown to me at the creation time. And I wondered if there's an STL function for that so I don't need to write a loop or not.

Comment: And BTW, the example I provided is exactly the one that made me wonder if there is such an STL function or not.

Comment: The standard algorithms either operate over ranges or require an input specifying number of times to iterate.   Your loop does neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps, if you absolutely insist on going out of your way to get STL to run loops for you:

```
class BitIterator {
 public:
  using value_type = int;
  using difference_type = std::size_t;
  using pointer = int*;
  using reference = int&;
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

  BitIterator(int n = 0) : n_(n) {}

  int operator*() const { return n_ & 1; }
  BitIterator& operator++() { n_ >>= 1; return *this; }

  bool operator==(const BitIterator& other) const { return n_ == other.n_; }
  bool operator!=(const BitIterator& other) const { return n_ != other.n_; }

 private:
  int n_ = 0;
};

std::vector<int> bits(int N) {
    return {BitIterator(N), BitIterator(0)};
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YGvoT338n)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me realize that I've got so much to learn.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how the `BitIterator` is helping construct the vector in your code. I believe you are calling the constructor of vector which takes in two `InputIt`s and an allocator. But since the allocator has a default value, you are not specifying it. If that's the case, then how a `BitIterator` can be passed in place of an `InputIt`? I mean, it's not its child class! The `BitIterator` is not inheriting from `InputIt`!

Comment: You may wish to read about templates in your favorite C++ textbook. "Templates 101" is too big a subject for a StackOverflow answer, let alone a comment.

Comment: OK, now I see it. The `InputIt` is not a class but a template type. Sorry, I had missed that part. I need to be more careful reading the docs :)